# Is it mandatory to set "restore_command" and "archive_cleanup_command" in recovery.conf?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am setting up a `PostgreSQL` (9.1 version) standby server in **`Streaming replication`** (not file-based log shipping).

Having set `standby_mode` to 'on' and `primary_conninfo` to a correct value, is it important or mandatory to set `restore_command`or `archive_cleanup_command`? And also `archive_command` in the master server?

I'm not very sure of the answer despite having read [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-OPERATION).

Thanks.

EDIT:

Let me answer my own question. In the recover.conf file, which must be present in the slave,  there is a comment for `restore_command` that says:

> ```
> # This parameter is *required* for an archive recovery, but optional
> # for streaming replication.
> ```

In conclusion, it is not necessary to configure the file log-shipping features (archiving, recovery, cleanup, etc) if your slave machine does not fall back too much from the master.

Answer (score 4):

You are required to set the `archive_command` on the master and set a matching `restore_command` on the slave.

The streaming replication system works by giving the wal record id to the slave which will get it by using the `restore_command`. So you have to have some kind of `archive_command` on the master which writes to a storage device that is accessible through the `restore_command` on the slave.

The `archive_cleanup_command` is optional but highly recommended as the wal archives take up a lot of diskspace and can fill up your disks quite fast.

Comment: `The streaming replication system works` so how to setup this streaming part ?

Comment: It might be most useful to look at the wiki to set it up: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication

Comment: this answer uses combination of streaming replication (direct wal transfer between primary-target) & log-shipping (archive-restore).
when you use only streaming replication, it works by directly sending wal record, so when both are combined, does it uses this method of sending only wal id and use restore to retrieve wal record ?

Comment: @Yusuf when both are combined the completed WAL files are sent/received with the archive_command/restore_command  AND after the slave is caught up on files it connects directly to the master to stream WAL records as they happen